# What codec do I need to play MP4-Videos on my pc? (offline)

Tags: codec

I am new to elementary OS, what codec do I need to play MP4 videos from my storage off-line?

I get this error message: `Oops! Audience kann diese Datei nicht wiedergeben! No URI set.` (in English: `Oops! Audience can't play this file !`)

Answer (score 12):

You should install the package ubuntu-restricted-extras in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I am seeing this issue with Flowblade and installing the restricted extras didn't resolve it. https://github.com/jliljebl/flowblade/issues/228